# Diferença entre o /dev/urandom e /dev/random

Tags: linux, random, números-aleatórios

Recentemente, li um [post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/943911) sobre o driver jdbc da oracle, falando que se fizesse a seguinte configuração na jvm rodando no Linux:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom
```

De acordo com a referencia, a geração de números randômicos com o urandom é mais rápida que o default, random. Qual é a diferença entre o urandom e random?

Comment: Ambos são tipos de geradores de número pseudo-aleatório (conhecido como PRNG). A diferença até onde eu saiba é como cada um gerencia o uso da entropia (que é fonte verdadeiramente aleatória), pode ver mais em https://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/.

Comment: Sua pergunta não tem relação com Java e muito menos com JDBC. O fato de você ter visto em um tópico sobre JDBC onde alguém falou de um problema que teve porque lá nas profundezas do driver JDBC da Oracle, são usados números aleatórios para alguma coisa, não faz com que conhecimento em Java ou em JDBC seja relevante para catalogar ou para responder a sua pergunta. Assim sendo, estou removendo essas duas tags da sua pergunta.

Comment: Além disso, qual é o motivo de usar `file:/dev/../dev/urandom` ao invés de simplesmente `file:/dev/urandom`?

Comment: Eu retirei a url `file:/dev/../dev/urandom` do post, por isso eu a mantive. Eu relacionei a java e jdbc, porque o driver da oracle sugere essa alteração em seus manuais. Devo editar a pergonta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Entropia]

<sub><sub>[Fonte](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/structure-new.png)</sub></sub>

Tanto o `/dev/urandom` quanto o `/dev/random` são capazes de gerar bits pseudo-randômicos com a diferença de que um está sempre disponível e o outro não.

Se o nível de entropia (do "Entropy Pool")  estiver abaixo o `/dev/random` deixará de funcionar, **em tese**. Enquanto isso na mesma situação o `/dev/urandom` continuará funcionando normalmente, mesmo em níveis críticos de entropia.

---

### Entropia:

Em resumo a entropia é um repositório de dados verdadeiramente aleatórios. Por exemplo, temperatura dos processadores, uso de disco, consumo energético, uso de rede de internet, uso do teclado, uso do mouse...

*Imagine que duas pessoas ligam o computador e entram num mesmo jogo online, uma pessoa pode usar uma sensibilidade diferente, cada jogador estará num ponto diferente do mapa fazendo andar mais e menos, a placa de vídeo renderizará pontos diferentes do mapa e o uso de memoria será diferente, o som produzido pelos passos e tiros serão diferentes.... No final  de uma partida a entropia coletada usando esses dados são completamente diferentes entre os dois jogadores, se então criptografássemos um trecho dessa entropia o resultado seria ainda mais diferente.*

A entropia é basicamente os bits coletados a partir das atividades daquele dispositivo. Existem também *hardwares*/dispositivos específicos para essa atividade, como por exemplo o [PQ4000KS](https://comscire.com/product/pq4000ks/) e o [TrueRNGpro](http://ubld.it/products/truerngpro) que tendem a produzir bits verdadeiramente aleatório e que podem ser utilizados como entropia pelo próprio sistema, assim criando entropia mais "forte".

Também existe o polemico [RdRand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) utilizado e integrado nos processadores da Intel, porém existem diversas críticas em relação ao seu uso. Ignorando isto o  RdRand seria um pequeno gerador verdadeiramente aleatório, assim abastecendo a entropia.

### Pseudo-Randômico ("PRNG"):

Primeiro é preciso *resumir* o que é o PRNG, ele constitui de duas bases:

**"Imprevisível" para "quem ver de fora"** (*mas previsível por dentro*):

Os bits gerados devem ser imprevisíveis para quem observa o resultado de fora do sistema, basicamente imagine gerar vários número de 0 até 9, deve ser impossível saber o próximo número baseado na resposta anterior. Se deu 5, não pode ser possível saber que o próximo é 6, ou que se o próximo for 7 o outro vai ser 2. Além disso se gerar 6,3,4,5,1,7,7,8,4,2 deve ser impossível descobrir qual "*seed*" está sendo utilizada.

**Uniformidade:**

Um pseudo-randômico deve gerar resultados com mesmas chances, as mesmas as chances de 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 devem ser igual se gerar um número de 0 até 9. Um pseudo-randômico não pode gerar mais 9 do que 0, por exemplo se gerar 10000 números (de 0 até 9) não pode apenas uma única vez ter resultado em `0` e em 5000 vezes gerar `9`.

O PRNG utiliza da entropia (que é verdadeiramente aleatória) para gerar outros bits. A entropia serve para gerar uma "senha", na verdade é gerada pelo CSPRNG, que gera uma hash dos bits da entropia, assim utiliza a hash resultante como uma "chave" (tecnicamente é mais chamado de *seed*) e por essa razão os algorítimos continuamente ficam "mudando de senha" (tecnicamente isso se chama *re-seeding*). Isso é feito para que possa garantir que gerará bits com maior segurança (*entenda "segurança" como: manter os dois itens acima, "imprevisível" e "uniforme", evitando que a seed pode ter sido "vazada" ou tenha ficado previsível de alguma forma*).

> *PS: Ficando claro que isso é uma tentativa de resumo, enfatizando pontos que acredito que seja importante! Porém existem outros detalhes, como gerar um CSPRNG baseado na entropia para então utilizar no PRNG que são bem importantes. Mas, para não haver confusão, o CSPRNG tem como base a criptografia, portanto não há "uniformidade" e deve ser verdadeiramente "imprevisível", seguindo as bases da criptografia...*

---

### `/dev/random` VS `/dev/urandom`:

**Semelhanças:**

- Ambos são pseudo-aleatórios.

**Diferença:**

- O `random` se não há entropia suficiente ele deixará de funcionar.
- O `random` utiliza o "Entropy Pool".
- O `random` mantêm o nível de entropia alto, *mesmo que não possa "consumir"*.
- O `urandom` não irá fazer o re-seed se não houver entropia suficiente, continuando a funcionar.
- O `urandom` funcionará mesmo após o *boot* do sistema, onde não existe entropia suficiente, *isso pode ser grave*.
- O `urandom` utiliza diretamente o resultado do CSPRNG não usando o "Entropy Pool".

---

### Qual utilizar?

Pessoalmente `urandom`, mas primeiro dizer quem também usa o `/dev/urandom`:

- [BoringSSL](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/) (OpenSSL do Google) [utiliza](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/2272/crypto/rand/urandom.c) `/dev/urandom`.
- [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/) utiliza o `/dev/urandom` (exceto para geração de chaves, pode ser alterado manualmente).
- [OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/3f5616d734a92fdf99ab827f21e5b6cab85e7194/INSTALL#L995-L1002) parece utilizar o `/dev/urandom`, *preciso verificar (me baseando em "On systems without /dev/urandom (or similar) device, it may be necessary to install additional support software to obtain a random seed.")*.

Agora os motivos de diferença entre os dois, que favorecem o `/dev/urandom`:

- Sempre está disponível, *exceto com o dispositivo recém ligado em alguns sistemas operacionais*, consequentemente o seu software será muito mais estável.
- Embora seja importante o re-seed, uma seed é suficiente para gerar muitos bits pseudo-randômicos.
- Em qualquer situação (baixa ou alta entropia) o que será utilizado é o resultado do CSPRNG. A CSPRNG é, por ser criptograficamente seguro, tem como base ter uma saída imprevisível, essa é umas das "regras" da criptografia, mesmo em baixa entropia. Somente em raros casos isso seria um problema, se realmente a situação tiver literalmente critica, porque aí nem mesmo o CSPRNG não terá entropia suficiente.

Para todos os propósitos aconselho utilizar o `/dev/urandom` o seu software será muito mais estável (sem interrupções inesperadas) e terá resultados pseudo-aleatórios. Se quer resultados verdadeiramente aleatório nenhum dos dois irá cumprir esse objetivo.

---

### Quando não usar o `urandom`?

Isso é delicado, geralmente para gerações de chaves de longa duração tende a acreditar que o uso do `random` seja melhor. Porém, boa sorte, vou aguardar digitar e mover o mouse ficar copiando arquivos para outro disco...

O uso do `random` para chaves de longa duração e emitidas com baixa periodicidade pode possível e recomendado, gerar uma chave por ano, ok. Porém se você vai gerar uma (ou mais) chave(s) a cada hora ou minuto isso pode passar a ser um problema, pois pode em diversas situações não haver como gerar as chaves devido ao `random` bloquear.

Isso piora se o uso do `random` feito por uma maquina diretamente. Imagine hipoteticamente que use um um `crontab` (uma tarefa agendada) para gerar uma nova chave por minuto, usando `random`. Não há como o software bater a cabeça no teclado para digitar alguma coisa, fazendo que fique sem chave por longo tempo, se for depender sempre desta chave já era.

O mesmo ocorre com as identificações de sessões, como os *cookies*, que precisam ser randômicos e não repetidos. Imagina ficar sem entropia e não há como gerar mais sessões?! Se utilizar o `random` isso pode ocorrer (isto é o comportamento padrão do PHP até o PHP 7, no PHP 7.1 em diante utiliza `urandom`, por exemplo).

O caso mais grave do `urandom` é no *boot* do sistema, quando com extrema certeza não haverá entropia suficiente e com certeza irá gerar dados extremamente previsíveis (em ambos os aspectos, para o sistema e para quem vê de fora). Algumas distribuições do linux, não sei se todas, guardam um arquivo na hora de desligar o sistema (não se aplica em caso de desligamento inesperado), assim quando liga o dispositivo o `urandom` utilizará o arquivo salvo como um *seed*. No caso do FreeBSD o `urandom` ficará bloqueado enquanto não houver entropia suficiente, apenas nesta situação.

Answer (score 6):

São geradores de ruídos de sistema, ou seja, entropia.
Esses ruídos são usados para fins de geração de números aleatórios e criptografia.
Os dois são nativos dos sistemas Unix e sistemas Unix-like como o GNU/Linux e outros.
O **/dev/urandom** pode ser usado para tudo **menos para fins de segurança**. Pois não há um sistema de travamento quando não atinge números entrópicos suficiente e, nesse caso, ele chuta o balde e diz: Que se dane! Vai assim mesmo.
Já o **/dev/random** não tem a cabeça quente. Ele é como um mestre supremo das artes marciais. Tem muita paciência e possui um bloqueio que só libera quando se consegue entropia(ruídos) suficiente para gerar encriptação da ordem de 4096 bits ou mais.
No windows o responsável por isso é o arquivo ksecdd.sys.
Vale lembrar que nos sistema Unix-Like esse arquivo não é algo físico, ele reside na memória e, atualmente, a despeito dos kerneis mais antigo ele é somente leitura por questão de segurança.
Bem é isso!
**PS:** 
Ele só gera os ruídos, entropia, para que o openssl e o gnupg e outras ferramentas de encriptação possam gerar chaves de encriptação. Quando a gente está a gerar uma chave no GNU/Linux muitas vezes não tem entropia o suficiente e o /dev/random ativa o bloqueio e ai vem aquela mensagem para a gente fazer algo tipo mover o mouse feito louco, teclar no teclado ou assoviar e chupar cana ao mesmo tempo para ver se ajuda a gerar mais ruido no sistema.
**PS2:** 
Os sistemas Unix-based como o GNU/Linux, usa, por padrão o **/dev/random** para fins de segurança. Como a maioria dos servidores e supercomputadores do mundo prezam por segurança, estabilidade e um código fonte que possa ser analisado para verificar que não exista nenhuma **linha de código spybot** seja de desenvolvedores da comunidade ou de organizações privadas ou governamentais, com certeza eles usam sistemas Unix-Like e, portanto, usam **/dev/random**, pois é o padrão dos sistema para fins de segurança.